# alert value of button by onClick

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a lots of buttons from PHP output with each buttons having different values:

```
<button class='add' value=".$row['cat_no']." onClick='addItem(value)'>Add To Cart</button>

$row['cat_no'] is data from mysql.
```

I want to check the button's value when I click it, so I use native JS below:

```
<script>
function addItem(value) {
            alert("this.value");}
</script>
```

It is not working...it just return `this.value.` In this case I don't think it is suitable to assign Id to `getElementbyId`, Pls help to check my mistake or suggest solution. Thanks.

Pls: I dont want to use JQUERY, just native JS.

Comment: `onClick='addItem(this.value)'` and `alert(value)`

Comment: Dont qoute the value instead.. use alert(value);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `alert(elmt.value);` like below. you should pass `this` to the function

```html
<button class='add' value="test value" onClick='addItem(this)'>Add To Cart</button>

<script>
function addItem(elmt) {
            alert(elmt.value);
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

the code below helps you retrieve the value of the element that triggered the event:

```
<button class='add' value="test value" onClick='addItem(this)'>Add To Cart</button>

<script>
  function addItem(sender) {
        alert(sender.value);
  }
</script>
```

However, this is filled with [code smells.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

I would suggest doing the code below

```
    <button id='add-to-cart' class='add' value="test value">Add To Cart</button>
```

On a separate JS file:

```
(function() {
    function _onLoad() {
        var addToCartButton = document.getElementById("add-to-cart");

         addToCartButton.addEventListener("click", _onAddToCartClicked);
    }

    function _onAddToCartClicked() {
        var sender = this;

        alert(sender.value);
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _onLoad, false);
})();
```

This approach ensures that:

1. Concerns are separated between HTML and JS
2. External JavaScript file would be cached which results to faster page load time.
3. UI would render faster since there are no inline scripts
4. Global namespace won't be polluted

Comment: Does it means all the rendered id from PHP will be the same?

Comment: Tis is new to me. R u saying tat it is the addeventlistener can do the trick to mark the button tat we click regardless of id is the same or not?

Comment: @P.Lau It doesn't mark the add to cart button. It is attach an event to the target HTML element without adding the event on the onclick property of the element. This is better because it allows you to group all your JavaScript on external files which improves maintainability, readability and performance of the page. It also doesn't necessarily mean that you have to give all elements with the same identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `this` in your function, just use `value`. And also remove double quotes, because you need to alert function's parameter, not string, like this:

```
function addItem(value) {
  alert(value);
}
```

Here is the working example:

```js
function addItem(value) {
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<button class='add' value="yourValue" onClick='addItem(value)'>Add To Cart</button>
```

Or you can pass the element to function using `this`, and then get the needed attribute value from `addItem` method:

```js
function addItem(item) {
  alert(item.value);
}
```

```html
<button class='add' value="yourValue" onClick='addItem(this)'>Add To Cart</button>
```